# Nginx caching angular js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, nginx

I have an angular site that im trying to publish to nginx, this is my nginx configuration. It works in routing to the pages:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.domain.com;

    root /home/user/angular/app/;

    index index.html;    

    location / {
        root /home/user/angular/app/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

As you can see it doesn't have anything on cache, and according to nginx doc it shouldn't cache anything that way.

But when i make changes in my js files (html changes are displayed correctly) thay are not refreshed accordingly (i see things i deleted from them, wrong behavior, etc)

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Try add_header Cache-Control no-cache; set should keep things from being cached. Take a look at this post: https://serversforhackers.com/nginx-caching

Comment: Are you seeing the webpage with the browser dev tools open? If so, try refreshing the page with Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: I tried the no cache header but it didnt make a difference, im using dev tools with no cache and testing from incognito as well. Maybe something to do with cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding this block of code to my conf file to prevent caching of JS files.

```
location ~* \.(?:html|js)$ {
  expires -1;
}
```